# How to exclude design document from couchdb query

Tags: python, couchdb, seaborn

I am trying to plot some data from couchdb database using seaborn:

```
sns.kdeplot(df4.Patient_Age)
```

This is what the data looks like:

```
000103f8-7f48-4afd-b532-8e6c1028d965    299
00021ec5-9945-47f7-bfda-59cf8918f10b    192
0002510f-fb89-11e3-a6eb-742f68319ca7    132
_design/searchID                        NA
```

How can one exclude the design document from showing up here? The `str` type causes  the error:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: NA
```

Answer (score 1):

Design documents are only included in the `/{db}/_all_docs` view. Any other view will not contain them.